# How can I prevent a column from being dragged out of the grid?

Tags: ag-grid

How can I prevent a column from being dragged out of the grid and be removed? I still want the column to be draggable and have column reordering, just don't want the removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the column being visible all the time, you can try this trick.

```
gridOptions = {

        onColumnVisible: function(e,c){
            if(!e.visible){
                e.column.gridOptionsWrapper.columnController.setColumnVisible(e.column.colId, true)
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach is to use the `lockVisible` property of the column.

You can apply it to all columns by adding it to the `defaultColDef` or apply it to individual columns.

```js
gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    lockVisible: true // by default, all columns cannot be removed
  },
  columnDefs: [{
      field: 'myField',
    },
    {
      field: 'myRemovableField',
      lockVisible: false // this column can be removed
    },
  ]
}
```